# Language in netstat output

Tags: locale, netstat

I have a program here, that depends on the output of `netstat`. More concrete: `netstat -apn`.

Here is an example of a normal output.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

A client of mine has some other output (as an example):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Endereço Local          Endereço Remoto         Estado      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       -
```

I want to test my software with a changed output of `netstat`, like the output of the client.

So the question is: What should I do to change the output language of `netstat`, so I can reproduce the errors, the client gets?

I already tried to change the language with `export LANG=pt_PT`, but the output didn't change.

Comment: What operating system are you using? If Linux, which one?

Comment: @terdon Operating System is Debian.

Comment: Ah, cool, then my answer should be relevant. Could you get it to work with Portuguese though? I couldn't get `netstat` to work, only other commands.

Comment: @terdon Yes it worked. Big thanks to you!

Comment: Really? Are you sure that's Debian and not Ubuntu?

Comment: The latest Debian 7.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your machine has the necessary locale set up. You can see available locales with `locale -a`. For example, on my system:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
el_GR.utf8
en_US.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
```

As you can see above, I don't have the Portuguese locale. On my Debian, I can create it by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and choosing the relevant locale:

Package configuration

```
 ┌──────────────────────────┤ Configuring locales ├──────────────────────────┐  
 │ Locales are a framework to switch between multiple languages and allow    │  
 │ users to use their language, country, characters, collation order, etc.   │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │ Please choose which locales to generate. UTF-8 locales should be chosen   │  
 │ by default, particularly for new installations. Other character sets may  │  
 │ be useful for backwards compatibility with older systems and software.    │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │ Locales to be generated:                                                  │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │    [ ] pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8                                              ↑   │  
 │    [ ] pt_PT ISO-8859-1                                               ▒   │  
 │    [*] pt_PT.UTF-8 UTF-8                                              ▮   │  
 │    [ ] pt_PT@euro ISO-8859-15                                         ▒   │  
 │    [ ] quz_PE UTF-8                                                   ↓   │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │                    <Ok>                        <Cancel>                   │  
 │                                                                           │  
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

After hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you should get:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  el_GR.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  fr_FR.UTF-8... done
  pt_PT.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

If you are not using a Debian-based distribution, you will need to do this manually:

1. Add the relevant locale name to `/etc/locale.gen`. For example:

   ```
   pt_PT.UTF-8 UTF-8
   ```
2. Run `locale-gen`

After the above steps (either the manual approach or the `dpkg-reconfigre locales` one), `locale -a` will also list the Portuguese locale:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
el_GR.utf8
en_US.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
pt_PT.utf8
```

Now, you can choose what language output is displayed in:

```
$ LC_ALL=el_GR.utf8 date
Τετ 14 Οκτ 2015 12:34:28 μμ EEST
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.utf8 date
mercredi 14 octobre 2015, 12:35:07 (UTC+0300)
$ LC_ALL=pt_PT.utf8 date
Qua Out 14 12:35:11 EEST 2015
```

However, whether or not a particular program is capable of printing output in the selected locale will depend on whether it has been translated; on whether the package ships with the relevant `.mo` translation file. In the case of `netstat`, this is `/usr/share/locale/${LANG%_*}/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo`. On my Debian, the French locale has it but the Portuguese one does not:

```
$ ls /usr/share/locale/{fr,pt}/LC_MESSAGES/net*
ls: cannot access /usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/net*: No such file or directory
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo
```

This is why I can run `netstat` in French:

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.utf8 netstat -apn | head -n2
(Tous les processus ne peuvent être identifiés, les infos sur les processus
non possédés ne seront pas affichées, vous devez être root pour les voir toutes.)
Connexions Internet actives (serveurs et établies)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat        PID/Program name
```

But not in Portuguese:

```
$ LC_ALL=pt_PT.utf8 netstat -apn | head -n2
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install language pack for the language you chose, otherwise the text translation utility ([gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) on GNU systems) can not translate the messages to your chosen language:

```
$ strace -fe trace=open sh -c 'LANGUAGE=fr_FR.utf8 netstat -tnlp'
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
Process 14847 attached
[pid 14847] open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 14847] open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 14847] open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 14847] open("/proc/3690/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid 14847] open("/proc/8579/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale/fr_FR.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale/fr.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr_FR.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14847] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
....
[pid 14847] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=14847, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=2} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can see the process try to look in `/usr/share/locale` and `/usr/share/locale-langpack` to get the translate text for `net-tools` package (which `netstat` belong to).

Now, install the language pack made it work. On Ubuntu system:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-fr
```

Other system, the relevant language pack for package can be include by the package itself, at least on Debian and Centos:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo
net-tools: /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo
```

(On Centos you can use `yum whatprovides`)

Then:

```
$ strace -fe trace=open sh -c 'LANGUAGE=fr_FR.utf8 netstat -tnlp'
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
Process 15155 attached
[pid 15155] open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 15155] open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 15155] open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 15155] open("/proc/3690/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid 15155] open("/proc/8579/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale/fr_FR.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale/fr.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr_FR.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15155] open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 15155] open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
(Tous les processus ne peuvent être identifiés, les infos sur les processus
non possédés ne seront pas affichées, vous devez être root pour les voir toutes.)
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       PID/Program name
....
[pid 15155] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=15155, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=3} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo` existed, `gettext()` successfully to translate the messages.

Note that not all words can be translated, my hometown `vi_VN` locale didn't work even if I installed the `language-pack-vi`.

---

You should use `LC_ALL` to override all other localisation settings, [except LANGUAGE in GNU system](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable) as above.